# Push browser notification - on click dynamic url

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker

I'm using push browser notifications in my project, everything is working fine except for clicking on notification, i want it to open dynamic url according to notification data

my code

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
  console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"`);

  const title = 'Garment IO';

  const options = {
    body: getAlertData(event.data.text()),
    icon: '../images/icon.png',
    dir:'rtl',
    badge: '../images/badge.png'
  };
  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Notification click Received.');

  event.notification.close();

  event.waitUntil(
    clients.openWindow('https://google.com');///want to change this !
  );
});
```

so is there any attribute i can push in event ? like url or sth ?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing only text into the push handler you can pass in a stringified  object (with `JSON.stringify()`), which you parse back into a object with `event.data.json()`. Then you can set the url as part of the data property of the notification object.

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  const myObject = event.data.json();
  const options = {
    body: myObject.bodyText,
    data: myObject.url,
    ...
  };
  return self.registration.showNotification(myObject.title, options);
});
```

The data object is later accessible in the "notificationclick" event

```
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url));    
});
```

Comment: I guess the idea is to open the URL on the notificationclick event, your code would open the URL right when receiving the push

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in the above answer, because url does not exist in `data`, as he said you have to pass a json string  with   `JSON.stringify()` and then convert it back to json with `data.json()`, so this my final correct code.

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
    console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.json()}"`);

    const myObject = event.data.json();
    //const title = 'Nueva Reserva Alpaca Expeditions';
    const options = {
      body: myObject.bodyText,
      data: myObject.url,
      icon: '/assets/icon.png',
      badge: '/assets/badge.png'
    };

    const notificationPromise = self.registration.showNotification(myObject.title, options);
    event.waitUntil(notificationPromise);
  });

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Notification click Received.');
  console.info(event.notification)
  event.notification.close();

  event.waitUntil(
    clients.openWindow(event.notification.data)
  );
});
```